# Call barring in Android

Tags: android-versions, call-screening

Is call barring is a native Android feature? I mean blocking of **outgoing** calls.

In [some Android articles](https://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/block-calls-android/) I see the screenshots where call barring is present in settings but in recent Android versions I don't see it.

In what Android release it appeared and since what it became deprecated (or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Based on OP's [clarification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220003/call-barring-in-android/220005?noredirect=1#comment284094_220005) in comments and subsequent search - **Call Barring** refers to both incoming and outgoing calls being blocked whereas **Call blocking/Number blocking** refers to only incoming calls being blocked.

To answer OP's question

- Call barring is not a standard Android OS feature.
- Call barring seems to be <s>Samsung</s> OEM specific. See [call barring - Samsung community](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/Other-Smartphones/Call-barring/td-p/259711). It also includes roaming calls

Thanks to [Andrew's inputs in comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220003/call-barring-in-android/220005?noredirect=1#comment284142_220005)

> call barring is usually available on most phones (e.g. [OPPO R11](https://devices.vodafone.com.au/oppo/r11-android-7-1/calls-and-contacts/turn-call-barring-on-or-off/)
> , [Huawei P10](https://devices.vodafone.com.au/huawei/p10-android-7-0/calls-and-contacts/turn-call-barring-on-or-off/)
> , and even on older feature phones), but the service is linked directly to the SIM provider. That's why it also asks for the code before changing the settings.

Section below is retained for reference, just in case this confusion arises again

---

[Number blocking](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#number-blocking) was introduced in Android 7 and it is not depreciated AFAIK. I have been using close to stock devices(Moto, Android One) and found this feature, usually in the SMS & phone apps. I am currently on Android 10 with Oxygen OS which is considered close to stock and this feature is present

Extracts below

> The default SMS app, the default phone app, and carrier apps can read from and write to the blocked-number list. The list is not accessible to other apps....
>
> Additionally, carrier app integration through Android means that carriers can read the blocked numbers list on the device and perform service-side blocking for the user in order to stop unwanted calls and texts from reaching the user through any medium, such as a VOIP endpoint or forwarding phones

The article you linked pre-dates Android 7 and mentions specifically that it is *not* a standard Android feature and goes on to give examples of OEM implementation. See [Implementing Block Phone Numbers](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/block-numbers) which says

> Before N, Android users had to rely on downloaded apps to restrict calls and texts from bothersome phone numbers. Many of those apps either do not work as desired or provide a less-than ideal experience because there are no proper APIs for blocking calls and messages.

Comment: However, call barring also allows blocking **outgoing** calls, as highlighted in my article, whilst standard Android framework you describe doesn't allow this. Am I correct?

Comment: If it is OEM implementation of barring, do you probably know which vendor it belongs to? Can you suggest it from screenshots or from your personal experience?

Comment: `Interesting point you made. I think you are right` in most dictionaries *barring* is defined/highlighted as **outgoing** call blocking ([1](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/call-barring.html), [2](https://www.reference.com/world-view/call-barring-14a4aa0d2b2f1ef)) and hence is my question and main point of interest. Incoming blocking is a standard feature and implemented by all vendors, outgoing is not.

Comment: AFAIK... call barring is usually available on most phones (e.g. [OPPO R11](https://devices.vodafone.com.au/oppo/r11-android-7-1/calls-and-contacts/turn-call-barring-on-or-off/), [Huawei P10](https://devices.vodafone.com.au/huawei/p10-android-7-0/calls-and-contacts/turn-call-barring-on-or-off/), [Sony Xperia X](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-X/how-to-disable-call-baring/td-p/1323000), and even on older feature phones), but the service is linked directly to the SIM provider. That's why it also asks for the code before changing the settings.

Comment: `but the service is linked directly to the SIM provider` yes, I am aware of carrier's barring, but the question was not about settings menu for enabling carrier barring, but about own independent implementation without subscription for additional carrier services. In my country they are not free

Comment: @Suncatcher Sorry I am not aware of how to do that. Thanks for accepting